# Firebase Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have implemented Firebase database by included assistant. 
It added to my gradle dependencies `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'`

after that, I couldnt build the procject (solution was to change impelentation into kapt)

My gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
        kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    }
```

Then, I needed to retreive a instance of my database

```
class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val manager = supportFragmentManager


    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
```

and its error,  *unresolved reference: FirebaseDatabase*

I have tried to deal with it, but it seems its beyond me.

Guys, any idea what is the reason ?

Comment: Change `kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
`  to `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4"
`

Comment: This is happening because you changed `implementation` to `kapt` - kapt runs during build time, but for it to be available as a library you actually want `implementation`. You should revert that change and give us more info on why the project wouldn't build. My guess you're missing `google()` in your repositories list, but I can't tell without the error.

Answer (score 8):

I face same problem today and I solve it by adding next line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.2.1'
```

but note I'm using higher ver. of Firebase

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'`
```

As you using firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0 may you need to add next line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

I hope it will work for you too.

Romuo

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start?authuser=0

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

check this for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android