# firebase_functions is an unresolved reference even tough I installed the needed dependencies

Tags: python, firebase

I have this standard boilerplate after trying to set up Firebase cloud functions and realtime database:

```
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

# initialize_app()
#
#
@https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

Even though I did pip install `pip install firebase_functions` I still get `Unresolved reference 'firebase_functions'`  from PyCharm. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this StackOverflow question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106203/firebase-unresolved-reference